# How to execute sql by getting dynamic table from mybatis without using ${}?

Tags: mybatis

I am trying to execute an sql statement by receiving a dynamic table.

If #{} is used, sql does not work because it is entered in the form of'layer_name'.

Therefore, I have to use ${}, but there is a problem that is vulnerable to sql injection.

```
<select id="test" parameterType="map" resultType="map">           
select 
    *
from
    ${table_name}
</select>
```

I want to use a procedure to solve this problem, but the return type is ambiguous because I have to do 'select all'.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: `${table_name}` is OK if you fully control the value of `table_name` from inside your app. If it's coming from the outside world, or entered by the user, then it's a no-no. What is your use case?

Comment: In my case, the user's input comes in and the table name is inferred using that input and then the query is executed.

Comment: @If it's *inferred* that could be safe. For example the users enters `1` or `2`, and then you produce the table name `employee` or `vehicle`, that's safe. Now, if the user types `employee` or `vehicle` and then you directly use that string into the SQL statement that produces SQL Injection. The key in what you said is the word *inferred*.